# Flash freezes when I pop up the Window Menu (Windows XP)

Tags: windows-xp, flash

We have various applications using flash, although we have encountered some problems when an user freezes flash , our application enters in a corrupted state because it did not received some packets or did not send some.

Currently I have not found anything about this problem neither in  Microsoft tech support nor in Flash community help, so if anyone could relate to this and specially aid into making flash not freezing could be very helpful.

Method to freeze a flash:

- SO : Windows XP (Any SP)
- Open a flash application (IE,Firefox,Chrome or Safari)
- Press Alt+SpaceBar
- The flash app appears to have been paused
- Return focus to the windows

PS: I would like some guidance into some technicall document that points out this bug or windows XP feature, so that at least we can consider this use of the app as a misbehave from the user side and not as a bug of our application.

Thank you.